# gtsummary - providing mean of means

Tags: gtsummary

```
library(gtsummary)

table1_test <- test %>%
  select(period,   hr_avg_relative, hr_max_relative )%>%
  tbl_summary(by = period, statistic = list(
    all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ± {sd} ",
    all_categorical() ~ "{n} / {N} ({p}%)"))%>%
  bold_labels()  %>%
  modify_header(label = "**Variable**" )
```

The previous working code provides a summary of ALL observations.

However, each id provides multiple observations. Instead of provinding a mean of all observations, can gtsummary provide the mean of each id's means?

df below

```
test <- structure(list(period = c("pre", "pre", "pre", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "post", "post", "post", "pre", "pre", "pre", "post", "post", 
"post"), id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), hr_max_relative = c(0.866279069767442, 
0.877906976744186, 0.802325581395349, 0.866279069767442, 0.918604651162791, 
0.872093023255814, 0.879120879120879, 0.857142857142857, 0.857142857142857, 
0.857142857142857, 0.89010989010989, 0.89010989010989, 0.941798941798942, 
0.873015873015873, 0.899470899470899, 0.899470899470899, 0.915343915343915, 
0.878306878306878, 0.844919786096257, 0.844919786096257, 0.855614973262032, 
0.903743315508021, 0.914438502673797, 0.866310160427808), hr_avg_relative = c(0.796511627906977, 
0.808139534883721, 0.761627906976744, 0.808139534883721, 0.837209302325581, 
0.813953488372093, 0.763736263736264, 0.796703296703297, 0.785714285714286, 
0.763736263736264, 0.802197802197802, 0.785714285714286, 0.878306878306878, 
0.793650793650794, 0.835978835978836, 0.835978835978836, 0.804232804232804, 
0.80952380952381, 0.689839572192513, 0.72192513368984, 0.754010695187166, 
0.754010695187166, 0.796791443850267, 0.786096256684492)), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```